# Rails Association using foreign key and through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables:

- **store**
- **point_of_sale** (attribute custom_point_of_sale_uuid is unique here acts as primary key)
- **pos_transaction**

When I try to join the tables to get the store name, I get `nil` values.

```
  @transactions = PosTransaction
    .where(:organization_id => "54846c4a-1517-43ff-8f02-e4b34de8a5a9")
    .joins(:point_of_sale)
    .joins(:store)
    .select('stores.name')
```

**point_of_sale** and **pos_transaction** are linked through `custom_point_of_sale_uuid`

What am I doing wrong?
Look at my graph of associations I made.

Thank you for help

[image]

Comment: Maybe just `PosTransaction.where(:organization_id => "54846c4a-1517-43ff-8f02-e4b34de8a5a9").point_of_sale.store.name`?

Comment: could you add the result of your query adding the explain method? `....select('stores.name').explain` ?

Comment: EXPLAIN for: SELECT stores.id FROM "pos_transactions" INNER JOIN "point_of_sales" ON "point_of_sales"."custom_point_of_sale_uuid" = "pos_transactions"."custom_point_of_sale_uuid" INNER JOIN "point_of_sales" "point_of_sales_pos_transactions_join" ON "point_of_sales_pos_transactions_join"."custom_point_of_sale_uuid" = "pos_transactions"."custom_point_of_sale_uuid" INNER JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "point_of_sales_pos_transactions_join"."store_id" WHERE "pos_transactions"."organization_id" = $1 [["organization_id", "54846c4a-1517-43ff-8f02-e4b34de8a5a9"]] QUERY PLAN

Comment: ------------------ Hash Join (cost=72.29..114.37 rows=1093 width=16) Hash Cond: ((point_of_sales.custom_point_of_sale_uuid)::text = (pos_transactions.custom_point_of_sale_uuid)::text) -> Seq Scan on point_of_sales (cost=0.00..14.70 rows=470 width=32) -> Hash (cost=66.47..66.47 rows=465 width=82) -> Hash Join (cost=33.62..66.47 rows=465 width=82) Hash Cond:

Comment: (point_of_sales_pos_transactions_join.store_id = stores.id) -> Hash Join (cost=13.95..40.94 rows=465 width=82) Hash Cond: ((point_of_sales_pos_transactions_join.custom_point_of_sale_uuid)::text = (pos_transactions.custom_point_of_sale_uuid)::text) -> Seq Scan on point_of_sales point_of_sales_pos_transactions_join (cost=0.00..14.70 rows=470 width=48) -> Hash (cost=11.47..11.47 rows=198 width=34) -> Seq Scan on pos_transactions (cost=0.00..11.47 rows=198 width=34)

Comment: Filter: (organization_id = '54846c4a-1517-43ff-8f02-e4b34de8a5a9'::uuid) -> Hash (cost=14.30..14.30 rows=430 width=16) -> Seq Scan on stores (cost=0.00..14.30 rows=430 width=16) (14 rows)

Comment: You're querying for an `organization_id` but I don't see that column in any of the tables in your graph. If you're trying to get the store name from a `pos_transaction`, you should be able to just do: `PosTransaction.where(...).joins(:store).select('stores.name')`

Answer (score 0):

You have this association in `pos_transaction`:

```
has_one :store, through: :point_of_sale
```

So you could just call:

```
@transactions = PosTransaction
.find_by(organization_id: "54846c4a-1517-43ff-8f02-e4b34de8a5a9")
.store.name
```

Comment: error in store.name: ´wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
Extracted source (around line #13):
    @transactions2 = PosTransaction
.where(:organization_id => "54846c4a-1517-43ff-8f02-e4b34de8a5a9")
.store.name

  end
end´

Comment: `where` returns a collection so you can't just call `.store` on it. If OP is looking for a collection of store names, replace `.store.name` with `.pluck('stores.name')`

Comment: @mmichael you are right, I have edited the response to use `find_by` instead of `where`.